# Using .append() with click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i want to replace the text in div when user click on it i have tried this code but there is something wrong with my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert('hi');
    $('div').append('hi')

    $('div').click(function(){
        $('this').append('how r u');

        })

    })
</script>
```

please help

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with it? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close!

`this` is a keyword in JavaScript, but you are using it as a string. Get rid of `'` around `this` and you should be fine!

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).append('how r u');
});
```

**Note**

If you want to replace the text, you should use `.html()` or `.text()` instead of `.append()`. Append will leave all text in the div as it is, and add the new text at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the text, use the `html` method

```
$('div').click(function(){
        $(this).html('how r u');

        })    
})
```

you dont need`'` with `this`.

working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/4xj72/1/

you can use `text()` method as well if there is no HTML markups you are adding.

http://jsfiddle.net/4xj72/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert('hi');
    $('div').append('hi')

    $('div').click(function(){
        $(this).append('how r u');

        })

    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('this').append('how r u');` should `$(this).append('how r u');`. `this` is a keyword there should not be `'` quotes around it.